# make excel auto generate number based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

i would like excel to generate row number based on the value in the cell.

```
 For example:(output) Columns  : A         B         C
                                 1         xx        xx
                                                     xx 
                                 2         yy        yy
                                                     yy
                                 3         zz        zz
                                                     zz
                                                     zz
```

In the event, i delete number 2, the 3 will become 2.

This is my existing code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 Then
If Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A")) + 1
Else
Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A")) - 1
End If
End If

End Sub

Function Max_Each_Column(Data_Range As Range) As Integer
    Dim TempArray() As Double, i As Long
        If Data_Range Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        With Data_Range
        ReDim TempArray(1 To .Columns.Count)
        For i = 1 To .Columns.Count
            TempArray(i) = Application.Max(.Columns(i))
        Next
    End With
        Max_Each_Column = TempArray
End Function
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use a countif formula?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an XY problem. But I think you are trying to index the first instance of each distinct value in Column C, maybe its a pivot table?

Put this formula in Cell A1 and copy down:

`=IF(B1<>"",COUNTA(B$1:B1)+1,"")`